# How are imports handled in package __init__.py files?

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.8

I ran across a very specific case where I cannot explain myself, why the python import does what it does and I am hoping you can help me. The set up is as follows:

```
root/
├── main.py
└── pack/
    ├── __init__.py  
    ├── db.py  
    └── plugins/
        ├── __init__.py  
        └── plug1/
           ├── __init__.py
           └── db.py
```

All files in the tree above are empty except `root/pack/plugins/plug1/__init__.py` which has the following content:

```
from pack.plugins.plug1 import db as plugin_db
from pack import db
```

and `main.py` with the following content:

```
import pack.plugins.plug1.db as plug_db
import pack.db as pack_db

print(pack_db.__file__)
print(plug_db.__file__)
```

When running `main.py` the output of the print statements is:

```
.../root/pack/db.py
.../root/pack/db.py
```

meaning the imported module is exactly the same.

My questions are:

1. Why are the imported modules the same?
2. Why does changing `from pack import db` to `from pack import db as pack_db` resolves the issue?

Comment: would be interesting to edit tags to show exact python version

Comment: These are some really bad name choices. Whoever set things up like this is causing problems for themselves.

Comment: I assume he's using python 2. Because in python 2, its own modules are considered global, which would result in the same import because of the same name situation (as commented above)

Comment: Nah, this would behave the same in 2 or 3 because of how the import order and shadowing work out.

Comment: I agree that the name choices are bad. But this results from a plugin architecture and the main focus of this question is the import mechanics of python itself.